# How can i change the every legend label font color using chart.js version 2.8.0 (spacial line chart)?

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chart.js version 2.8.0. I have encountered a problem. The problem is that I have to change the color of the every legend label. How do I change the color of the every label in this version (2.8.0)

Note: (I have no way yo use latest version for this satiation)

```
data: {
                    labels: [
                        "Sep",
                        "oct",
                        "Nov",
                        "Dec",
                        2020,
                        "Feb",
                        "Mar",
                        "Apr",
                        "May",
                        "jun",
                        "Jul",
                    ],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Fees",
                            fill: true,
                            // backgroundColor: "#FCBB0A",
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "red",
                            borderColor: "red",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "red",
                            borderCapStyle: "butt",
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            data: [-200, 200, -230, -100, -200, 190, 220, -350, 180, -200, 500],
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Interest",
                            fill: true,
                            // backgroundColor: "#FCBB0A",
                            backgroundColor: "green",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "green",
                            borderColor: "green",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "green",
                            borderCapStyle: "butt",
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            data: [-200, 200, 230, -100, -200, 190, 220, 350, 180, -200, 0],
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Net Positive",
                            fill: true,
                            // backgroundColor: "#FCBB0A",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(68,208,99,0.53)",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(68,208,99,0.53)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(68,208,99,0.53)",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(68,208,99,0.53)",
                            borderCapStyle: "butt",
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            data: [-200, 200, 230, -100, -200, 190, 220, 350, 180, -200, 0],
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Net Negative",
                            fill: true,
                            // backgroundColor: "#FCBB0A",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(243,86,86,0.53)",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(243,86,86,0.53)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(243,86,86,0.53)",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(243,86,86,0.53)",
                            borderCapStyle: "butt",
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            data: [-200, 200, 230, -100, -200, 190, 220, 350, 180, -200, 0],
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Net Value",
                            fill: true,
                            // backgroundColor: "#FCBB0A",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(86,170,243,0.53)",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(86,170,243,0.53)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(86,170,243,0.53)",
                            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(86,170,243,0.53)",
                            borderCapStyle: "butt",
                            stacked: true,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            data: [-200, 200, 230, -100, -200, 190, 220, 350, 180, -200, 0],
                        },
                    ],
                },
                options: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    showPoints: false,
                    showLine: false,
                    stacked: true,
                    tooltips: {enabled: false},
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    line: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        showLine: false,
                    },
                    elements: {
                        point: {
                            radius: 0,
                        },
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: "bottom",
                        align: "center",
                        labels: {
                            generateLabels: function(chart) {
let labels Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);

                        labels[0].fillStyle = 'blue';
                        labels[0].fontColor =   '#666'
                        labels[0].strokeStyle = 'green'
                            labels[0].fontSize = 14
                            return labels;
                            }
                        }
                    },
               
                    animation: {
                        duration: 750,
                    },
                },
```

But `labels[0].fontColor =  '#666'` and  `labels[0].fontSize = 14` not working

How can solve this problem please help me anyone

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do it in the generateLabels part you need to set it as a property in the labels config like so:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
        fontColor: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
```

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```